# Issue with Xamarin App and Web API Model Binding: Object passed to service is null only on iOS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, parameters, xamarin.ios

I have been running into a very strange issue, and I am not even sure if this is an issue with my app or the web service I am calling.

I have a Web API Service with a Post method that accepts a complex parameter (it is my own custom object). In my Xamarin project I have some pretty straightforward code to call this service:

```
public async Task SubmitEReport(decimal amount, DateTime receivedDate, 
byte[] image)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        var uri = new Uri("https://services.example.com/EPub/api/Expense/");

        var eReport = new eReport()
        {
            UserName = "EMPLOYEE\" + Application.Current.Properties["username"].ToString(),
            Cost = amount,
            ReceivedDate= receivedDate,
            ReceiptImageExtension = "jpg",
            SubmittalDate = DateTime.Now,
            Image = image
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eReport );

        var content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        content.Headers.Add("authorize-token", Application.Current.Properties["auth-token"] as string);

        HttpResponseMessage response = null;

        response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

        var eResult = new EResult()
        {
            Success = response.IsSuccessStatusCode,
            ErrorMessage = response.ReasonPhrase


        };

        return eResult ;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var errorResult = new eResult () { Success = false, ErrorMessage = ex.Message };
        return errorResult;
    }
}
```

The issue that I am having is that, when I test this on an Android the code works as expected: the service is called, the object passed over is not null and has the data in it. In short, the parameter binding works as expected. The same is not so on iOS: when I call the service using the app on an iPhone, I can see that it is reaching the service and the Post method, but the parameter binding is not working correctly as the object I am passing over is always null.

Comment: Have you inspected the request using some thing like fiddler to see what exactly is hitting the server when called from iOS device?

Comment: In your previous question you showed what is sent from the Android device. Check the actual message sent across the wire. Include that for our inspection and lets see if there are any discrepancies in the data sent.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I downloaded fiddler and I am going to do this and post back.

Comment: Good, It could be something as simple as test encoding, which could be different because of the different OS but we wont know till we look at the actual requests sent

Comment: I have yet to inspect the request, but I did make a breakthrough. When the "Image" property is set to null before the service is called, the object is received properly. Something seems to be happening with the "Image" property, which is of type byte[].

Comment: Do you think it could be because of the size of the image? Thinking out loud. But then again it works on Android. hmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved. The problem was actually the size of the request. I discovered this in my Web Api service after examining the contents of the request object, and received an exception that the request length was exceeded. My solution was to increase the value of the property maxrequestlength in the web.config. This still does not explain why the request is so much larger in iOS than Android. Will follow up on this.

Answer (score -1):

try to debug your code without using any async methods. async methods should work in general without any problems, but it's sometimes hard to comprehend how implemented logic actually behaves.